# Grails - storing Date in MySQL db loses time component

Tags: grails

I'm having a rather puzzling problem in a Grails 2.2.5 web application with a Date field. I have a Policy domain class, which has an 'issued' property, of type Date. There is no special mapping for it, so defaults will be used for GORM. In the MySQL database, it's defined thus:

`issued` datetime DEFAULT NULL

When I assign a date (such as new Date()) to 'issued', I can see from the log that it is correctly assigned:

2014-11-12 06:55:53,014 [http-bio-127.0.0.1-8001-exec-3] INFO  test.PolicyService  - Recording issued date as Wed Nov 12 06:55:53 EST 2014

But when I test it again, immediately after policy.save(), it's lost the time component:

2014-11-12 06:55:53,051 [http-bio-127.0.0.1-8001-exec-3] INFO  test.PolicyService  - issued date after save = Wed Nov 12 00:00:00 EST 2014

I cannot see any reason why this might be. The data type of the column can certainly take a time component (and I can explicitly set one). Somehow the time component is being erased, and I don't really know where to look.

Comment: You could try turning on mysql logging (add `general_log=1` and
`general_log_file=/tmp/mysql_query.log` to `my.cnf`) - see if hibernate is actually sending the time component to the db...

Comment: is the time component missing in the db table as well?

Comment: Yes, the time component is missing in the database. I haven't tried mysql logging itself yet, but I've tried Hibernate logging within Grails and can see that Hibernate is at least attempting to send the time component. For example, I see something like: 'binding parameter [77] as [TIMESTAMP] - Wed Nov 12 08:18:40 EST 2014'. But in the db itself, the value is '2014-11-12 00:00:00', and when I load it back into Grails, the time component is indeed gone.

Comment: Something which I don't suppose is connected, but is a puzzle to me, is that some Date properties get assigned like this: `binding parameter [77] as [TIMESTAMP] - Wed Nov 12 08:18:40 EST 2014`, and some get assigned like this: `binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - 2014-11-12 08:18:39.0`. The properties appear to be defined identically, and both are populated by having new Date() assigned to them, so it seems to be random, although I'm sure it can't be.

Comment: When you say "test" are in test environment?  If so, nothing will persist...that's how testing works.

Comment: No, nothing to do with testing, this is in a live working system which I've been working on for 18 months. It's completely mystifying to me. The 'dateCreated' and 'lastUpdated' properties, which are automatically timestamped by Grails, are defined as Date within my domain class just as my 'issued' property is, and are similarly mapped as 'datetime' in MySQL. They retain the time component when the object is saved, but 'issued' does not, and I cannot see any difference whatsoever to explain this.

Comment: I should add that there is a difference, but one which shouldn't explain this. They're NOT NULL and this one is nullable.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, thank goodness, turned out to be coding error on my part rather than some weird MySQL/Grails bug. I was sure all along that that must be the case, but just couldn't see where it might be. But in the end I discovered the culprit buried in a 'postUpdate' event handler. I had 'copied' the 'issued' property to another date variable and later used clearTime() on that object, forgetting that this would also clear time on the 'issued' property (because, of course, it wasn't a copy at all, just a new reference to the same object). I changed it to use a new Date object initialized with getTime() from the 'issued' property, and all is now well. Clumsy error!

I missed this because I was looking for anywhere a value was being assigned to 'issued', and this doesn't fall into that category.